# Node js email Invalid sender

Tags: node.js, email

Config : Ubuntu 16.04 LTS / Nginx

I'm trying to send mail with nodemail but I have this error :

```
{ [Error: Invalid sender "contact@example.com>"] code: 'EENVELOPE', command: 'API' }
```

Here is my code.

```
    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(
        smtpTransport('smtps://contact%40example.com:mypassword@smtp.example.com')
    );

    var text = 'Hello world from \n\n' + req.body.name;

    var mailOptions = {
        from: 'contact@example.com>', // sender address
        to: 'address@gmail.com', // list of receivers
        subject: 'Email Example', // Subject line
        text: text //, // plaintext body
        // html: '<b>Hello world ✔</b>' // You can choose to send an HTML body instead
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
            res.json({yo: 'error'});
        }else{
            console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
            res.json({yo: info.response});
        };
    });
```

With postfix on my server my mail works well I can send an email to an gmail address but with node js I have this error.

Comment: from: 'contact@example.com>', im like 99% sure than symbol > responsible for that. You have invalid email that's why you got an error. Change 'contact@example.com> to 'contact@example.com and all should be valid. Hope this helps.

Comment: Omg, kill me. Thanks a lot dude.

Comment: I did the same things, ugh thanks